# Получить значение одной строки массива, который расположен в массиве (JSON + PHP)

Tags: php, json

Вот мой JSON запрос который я получаю:

```
{
    "id": "*******",
    "inv": "0",
    "amount": "0.00",
    "type_curr": "WMZ",
    "sign": "***************************",
    "lang": "",
    "options": [
        {
            "id": "******",
            "type": "text",
            "user_data": "******"
        }
    ]
}
```

Когда я вызываю функцию foreach на этот декодированный запрос, я получаю это:

```
*******00.00WMZ************************<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\getemail.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
Array
```

И самая важная часть:

```
"user_data": "******"
```

Превращается в **Array**

И что мне делать, что-бы просто получить значение в **user_data**

Вот код:

```
<?php
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А код где?

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $param => $val) {
   if($param == 'options') {
      foreach($val) {
          // Обработка массива 'options'
      }
   }
}
```

А если нужно получить только `user_data`, `foreach` тут ни к чему:

```
echo $data['options'][0]['user_data'];
```

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: user_data in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\getemail.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

Comment: Напиши код, который выдает такую ошибку! Сначала делаешь json_decode(.., true) - получаешь многомерный массив. Далее идешь на php.net и куришь, как работать с массивами. Также неплохо делать промежуточные print_r(), чтобы понимать, с какими данными работаешь.

Comment: <?php
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);
?> + твой echo $data['options']['user_data'];

Comment: А ты сделай до моего echo var_dump($data) и посмотри, что там у тебя.

Comment: Только что проверил, это массив

Comment: Ну да, массив, раз на индекс ругается, но какой? Добавь в вопросе вывод print_r()

Comment: Array
(
    [id] => 2816168
    [inv] => 0
    [amount] => 0.00
    [type_curr] => WMZ
    [sign] => f74f0875a2167c9728bde3a0fa959034
    [lang] => 
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 114813
                    [type] => text
                    [user_data] => 114813
                )

        )

) - это выдал print_r($data);

Comment: Ах, да, конечно, echo $data['options'][0]['user_data'];

Comment: Спасибо, сам подумав тоже разобрался, правда ты меня обогнал